# Displaying the keys value from a JSON array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I get the league titles from the given JSON to show in [TITLE]? Everything else works just fine, but I would like for it to show up in league categories.

My HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="LeaguesCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="league in leagues">
            League:  {{[TITLE]}}
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="match in league">
                    <td>{{match.home_team}}</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>{{match.away_team}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#">{{match.home_odds}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">{{match.draw_odds}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">{{match.away_odds}}</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

My JSON:

```
{
  "UEFA Champions League": [
    {
      "id": 152494,
      "home_team": "APOEL Nicosia",
      "home_short": "",
      "away_team": "Paris SG",
      "away_short": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 152519,
      "home_team": "Chelsea",
      "home_short": "",
      "away_team": "Maribor",
      "away_short": ""
    }
  ],
  "Barclays Premier League": [
    {
      "id": 126938,
      "home_team": "Arsenal",
      "home_short": "",
      "away_team": "Hull",
      "away_short": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 126942,
      "home_team": "Manchester C",
      "home_short": "Man C",
      "away_team": "Tottenham",
      "away_short": "Man C"
    }
  ]
}
```

My AngularJS controller:

```
myApp("LeaguesCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://api.odds24.com/best-odds?user=dev&leagues=SOCENGPRE,SOCINTCHL,SOCESPPRI').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.leagues = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify in the ng-repeate, so like this;

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-controller="LeaguesCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, league) in leagues">
        League:  {{key}}
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="match in league">
                <td style="padding: 0 5px">{{match.home_team}}</td>
                <td style="padding: 0 5px">-</td>
                <td style="padding: 0 5px">{{match.away_team}}</td>
                <td style="padding: 0 5px; text-align: right"><a href="#">{{match.home_odds}}</a></td>
                <td style="padding: 0 5px; text-align: right"><a href="#">{{match.draw_odds}}</a></td>
                <td style="padding: 0 5px; text-align: right"><a href="#">{{match.away_odds}}</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then just use `{{key}}` .

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FjvTFqnD4DZoNabjMGJh?p=preview).

Comment: how to do this in angular 7?

Answer (score 0):

You would just use the key/value option in the ng-repeat. So it would look something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="name, detail in league">
```

You then just reference it by using `{{name}}`.

More info in the docs for [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) page.